# Heroku DNS inconsistent

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

I set up DNS for my domain (payments.trylemontree.com) almost a week ago and it seems like it only works inconsistently. On my machine I get a 404 error, but a co-worker sees a successful page load...

Running `heroku domains` shows that it is setup correctly:

Running `host payments.lemontree.com`

```
payments.trylemontree.com is an alias for payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com.
payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com has address 34.206.9.96
payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com has address 34.206.253.53
payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com has address 34.206.36.121
payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com has address 52.204.188.97
payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com has address 52.1.35.184
payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com has address 52.1.65.199
payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com has address 52.20.145.121
payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com has address 34.204.22.7
```

Running heroku domains returns the following:

```
=== lemontree-payments Heroku Domain
lemontree-payments.herokuapp.com

=== lemontree-payments Custom Domains
Domain Name                DNS Record Type  DNS Target
─────────────────────────  ───────────────  ───────────────────────────────────────
payments.trylemontree.com  CNAME            payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com
```

When I run a DNS test via [pingdom](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=payments.trylemontree.com) It says that `Delegation not found at parent.`. I'm not sure what that means.

The namecheap setup is as follows:

```
CNAME Record   payments   payments.trylemontree.com.herokudns.com.

CNAME Record   payments   payments.trylemontree.com.herokussl.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your domain name is still served by nameservers `ns4.worldnic.com.` and `ns3.worldnic.com.` and for your name they do not reply with a `CNAME` record but with this:

```
payments.lemontree.com. 3600 IN A 104.200.29.150
```

So you need either to configure these two nameservers correctly, or switch, through your regitrar, to the appropriate nameservers.

You can have a look at http://dnsviz.net/d/payments.lemontree.com/W2hv1Q/dnssec/ to see the current resolution.